# Gameobject ( spotlight ) is not interacting/changing with UI canvas textField

Tags: c#, visual-studio, firebase, unity-game-engine

Gameobject ( spotlight ) is not responding with the UI ( text )

my intention is to fetch the value from firebase using rest api and blink the light according to values , the problem is here it is fetching the values very correctly but i cant interface to the gameobject

for example :

Under firebase 
   value : 75 (key - value pair)

it is fetched correctly but according to values it is not changing the color

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Proyecto26;

public class valuesRetrieve : MonoBehaviour
{
    int l;
    Color color0 = Color.red;
    Color color1 = Color.green;

    Light lt;

    public Text displayName;
    public InputField nameText;
    public static string name;

    public Text valueText;
    public static int store_values;

    User user = new User();

    void Start()
    {
        onSubmit();

        //l = liver(l);
        //lt = GetComponent<Light>();
    }

    public void onSubmit()
    {
        RetrieveFromDatabase();
    }

    private void RetrieveFromDatabase()
    {
        RestClient.Get<User>("https://feelsmart-******.firebaseio.com/" + nameText.text + ".json").Then(response =>
        {
            user = response;

            UpdateValues();
        });
    }

    public void UpdateValues()
    {
        valueText.text = "store value is " + user.StoreValues;

        lt = GetComponent<Light>();
        //user.StoreValues = 75;
        if (user.StoreValues < 72 || user.StoreValues > 80)
        {
            lt.color = color0;
        }
        else
        {
            lt.color = color1;
        }
 }
```

I expect the color to be changed

[image: screenshot of my object scenes]

Comment: You might want to try GetComponentInChildren<> instead of GetComponent<>. See the exception you are getting. Also make sure that there is actually a light component attached to those Spot Light objects.

Comment: yes @Reasurria that really makes sense ! I ve forgot to attach the light object to the script , which am trying , thnx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a `MissingComponentException`:

> There is no "Light" attached to the "GameObject" game object, but a script is trying to access it.

```
lt = GetComponent<Light>();
```

tries to get the component `Light` of the **same** GameObject that script is attached to.

---

In case you want to change only the first found child `Light` you have to use [`GetComponentInChildren<Type>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html)

```
// GetComponentInChildren by default only finds active and enabled components
// -> use true if you want to also get components if they are disabled
// or the GameObject inactive
light = GetComponentInChildren<Light>();

light.color = (user.StoreValues < 72 || user.StoreValues > 80) ? color0 : color1;
```

Or in case you want to change all `Light`s under that object you have to use [`GetComponentsInChildren<Type>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html) (mind the `s`) and iterate over them

```
// GetComponentsInChildren by default only finds active and enabled components
// -> use true if you want to also get components if they are disabled
// or the GameObject inactive
lights = GetComponentsInChildren<Light>(true);
foreach(var light in lights)
{
    light.color = (user.StoreValues < 72 || user.StoreValues > 80) ? color0 : color1;
}
```

Comment: thanks @derHugo it worked like a charm ! i ve forgot to attach the object to scripts too!